# Neutrino oscillations in Cheng and Li

Tags: quantum-field-theory, neutrinos

Cheng & Li's Gauge theory of elementary particle physics has the following formula for the average intensity of neutrino oscillations (Eqs 13.30 and 13.31) on p 411.
\begin{align}
\langle P_{\nu_e\longrightarrow \nu_e}\rangle  &=  1 - 2 c_1^2 s_1^2 -2 s_1^4 c_3^2 s_3^2\nonumber\\
\langle P_{\nu_e\longrightarrow \nu_\mu}\rangle & = 2 c_1^2 s_1^2 c_2^2 + 2 s_1^2 s_3^2 c_3^2 (s_2^2 - c_1^2 c_2^2) + 2 s_1^2 s_2 s_3 c_1 c_2 c_3 (s_3^2 -c_3^2) \cos \delta \nonumber\\
\langle P_{\nu_e\longrightarrow \nu_\tau}\rangle  & = 2 c_1^2 s_1^2 s_2^2 + 2 s_1^2 s_3^2 c_3^2 (c_2^2 - c_1^2 s_2^2) + 2 s_1^2 s_2 s_3 c_1 c_2 c_3 (s_3^2 -c_3^2) \cos \delta 
\end{align}
where $c_i = \cos \theta_i$, $s_i = \sin \theta_i$ ($i=1,2,3$) with the $\theta_i$ and $\delta$ the parametrisation of the KM (or PMNS) matrix.  $\langle P_{\nu_e\longrightarrow \nu_e}\rangle$ is the probability of having a $\nu_e$ at a distance much larger than the oscillation length when starting from a $\nu_e$, etc.

One would expect these three probabilities to add to one, but this is not the case from the formula above. The terms independent of $\delta$ do indeed sum to one, but there is a term that depends on $\cos \delta$.

Is this a typo in Cheng & Li, or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably a typo. What does your own direct calculation require/suggest?

Comment: I have only checked the electron neutrino one. Guess I have to check the other ones as well now.

Comment: For completeness: the expression for the muon neutrino checks out as well, but not the one for the tau neutrino. So I guess that one has a sign error in the $cos \delta$ term. There seems to be a typo in the KM matrix (13.22) as well. This should be the same as (12.40), but the entry (3,2) is different.  Unfortunately it seems that neither (12.40) nor (13.22) leads to (13.31).

Comment: You are right the (3,2) entry you identified is also flakey. You may make life easier by choosing $\theta_1=0$, $\theta_2=\pi/2$ and noting what remains is not an orthogonal/unitary matrix... Have you checked for errata sheets, or subsequent editions? The PDG reviews should have solid, vetted versions.

Comment: (14.6) of the [PDG 2018 review](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf), with different conventions, is the one to follow. It is stable, vetted, and the standard in the community. Li & Cheng is a tasteful, pioneering,  and wonderful pedagogical text, but it is not a "working" text for detailed calculations....

Comment: There is mention of an Errata page [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173578/is-there-a-mistake-in-a-qft-textbook), but the link has rotted... you could bother to pursue its descendants, but why...?